# Inserting a character count, that only counts certain sections

Tags: word-count

Is it possible for LaTeX to count the characters (including space) within certain sections (or rather discluding this like abstract and bibliography). And insert the number as a variable within the text it self?

The reason being is my teacher wants a character count on the front page, that discludes non essential parts.

Comment: what is a "character" here?  how many characters are in `find`given that latex uses a single ligature glyph for `fi` the number asked for is meaningless, especially if you include `space`  (if `\hspace{1em}` count as as 1 character what does `\hspace{2em}` count as, or a stretchable space like `\hfill`?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-word-count-and-more-825d4ccd-082b-4578-a621-66dfe27cdf48 maybe you can count them using Word. That's at least a quick way. Just copy and paste the relevant text from the pdf into a new Word document. I am sure that your teacher will accept the counting algorithm from Word since it's very common.

Comment: Do you know about [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/)? Also, what a *horrible* teaching style. You can talk and talk and talk all day and never say a meaningful word. That's not communication. *sigh*

Comment: [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/), which Sean mentioned, can count the letters and there are ways to [import the count into the document](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#includecount). However, TeXcount doesn't include the spaces in the count. The simple way to bypass this is to run TeXcount twice: count words, count letters, and add the two using the word count as a proxy for the number of spaces.